# draw rectangle tkinter not functioning

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, draw

Below is the code to draw a rectangle by click drag and release... For some reason its not working, the canvas screen is showing up but the rectangle isn't being drawn? Is it the root.mainloop() line? Because I changed it because I needed to draw arcs and lines and couldn't just have app = rectangle and app.mainloop... Sorry I'm really new to this.

```
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk, mainloop
import tkinter as tk 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Image dimensions
w,h = 800,400

# Create canvas
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = w, height = h, bg='#D2B48C', cursor = "cross")
canvas.pack()


class Rectangle(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.release)
        self.rect = None
        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None

    def press(self, event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, fill="red")

    def move(self, event):
        mouseX, mouseY = (event.x, event.y)

        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, mouseX, mouseY)

    def release(self, event):
        pass

# Other Classes for arc and pencil begin here

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ***@BryanOakley*** comments, the provided source contains uncompleted analysis and reveals misunderstandings of tkinter use.

**Problem 1** - the `class Rectangle` doesn't need to inherit from `tk.Tk`.

> Instead of inheriting the `class Rectangle` from `tk.Tk`, add the
>   `Canvas` instance at instance creation.

```
 class Rectangle(): # not inherit from ==> tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,canvas):
        # not initialize a second Tk instance ==> tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        #  attach the main canvas
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = True)
```

Instead of:

```
class Rectangle(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = True)
```

**Problem 2** - no instance of the `class Rectangle` has been created.

> To use the `class Rectangle`, an instance shall be created and
>   attached to the `canvas` instance !!
>
> Before, move the class declaration before `Tk()` and `Canvas()`
>   creation.

```
class Rectangle(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
...
    def release(self, event):
        pass

# Other Classes for arc and pencil begin here

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = w, height = h, bg='#D2B48C', cursor = "cross")
canvas.pack()

# create the Rectangle instance
hRect = Rectangle(canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Instead of:

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = w, height = h, bg='#D2B48C', cursor = "cross")
canvas.pack()

class Rectangle(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
...
    def release(self, event):
        pass

# Other Classes for arc and pencil begin here

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, you never create an instance of the `Rectangle` class which is where all your logic is.

For another, you must only have a single instance of `Tk`. You create one at the start of the problem, and then you'll create another if you create an instance of `Rectangle`. Again, you can only have one.

Comment: How do I do that...?

Comment: And which instance of Tk should I delete?